# How to combine/concatenate two dataframes one after the other but not merging common columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind, cbind

Suppose there are two dataframes as follows with same column names and I want to combine/concatenate one after the other without merging the common columns. There is a way of assigning it columnwise like df1[3]<-df2[1] but would like to know if there's some other way.

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(1:10), B=c(2:5, rep(NA,6)))
df2<-data.frame(A=c(12:20), B=c(32:40))
```

Expected Output:

```
A  B  A.1 B.1
1  2  12  32
2  3  13  33
3  4  14  34
4  5  15  35
5  NA 16  36
6  NA 17  37
7  NA 18  38
8  NA 19  39
9  NA 20  40
10 NA NA  NA
```

Comment: Try `rowr::cbind.fill(df1, df2, fill = NA)`

Answer (score 1):

I tend to work with multiple frames like this as a [list of frames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227). Try this:

```r
LOF <- list(df1, df2)
maxrows <- max(sapply(LOF, nrow))
out <- do.call(cbind, lapply(LOF, function(z) z[seq_len(maxrows),]))
names(out) <- make.names(names(out), unique = TRUE)
out
#     A  B A.1 B.1
# 1   1  2  12  32
# 2   2  3  13  33
# 3   3  4  14  34
# 4   4  5  15  35
# 5   5 NA  16  36
# 6   6 NA  17  37
# 7   7 NA  18  38
# 8   8 NA  19  39
# 9   9 NA  20  40
# 10 10 NA  NA  NA
```

One advantage of this is that it allows you to work with an arbitrary number of frames, not just two.

Answer (score 1):

One base R way could be

```
setNames(Reduce(cbind.data.frame, 
                Map(`length<-`, c(df1, df2), max(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)))),
         paste0(names(df1), rep(c('', '.1'), each=2)))
#     A  B A.1 B.1
# 1   1  2  12  32
# 2   2  3  13  33
# 3   3  4  14  34
# 4   4  5  15  35
# 5   5 NA  16  36
# 6   6 NA  17  37
# 7   7 NA  18  38
# 8   8 NA  19  39
# 9   9 NA  20  40
# 10 10 NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need `Map`, this works equally well with `lapply(c(df1, df2), \`length<-\`, max(nrow(df1), nrow(df2)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `merge` function. The documentation can be a bit cryptic, so here is a short explanation of the arguments:

- `by` -- "the name "row.names" or the number 0 specifies the row names"
- `all = TRUE` -- keeps all original rows from both dataframes
- `suffixes` -- specify how you want the duplicated colnames to be distinguished
- `sort` -- keep original sorting

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 0, all = TRUE, suffixes = c('', '.1'), sort = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be

``````
cbind(
   df1,
   rbind(
      df2,
      rep(NA, nrow(df1) - nrow(df2))
   )
)
`````
``````